# Error Retrieved src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ah:AppHdr' to a(n) 'element declaration' component

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have set of 5 xsd's where 1 is parent and rest are child which are imported
All xsd's are in single location and i have used maven plugin to generate the pojo classes.

This is my sample GenerateXML Class

```
        MainMsg1 mmsrMessage = new MainMsg1();
    //JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MainMsg1.class);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MainMsg1.class, ObjectFactory.class,
            com.mypackage.appheader.ObjectFactory.class,
            com.mypackage.doc1.ObjectFactory.class,
            com.mypackage.doc2.ObjectFactory.class,
            com.mypackage.doc3.ObjectFactory.class,
            com.mypackage.doc4.ObjectFactory.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    //Document doc = objf.createDocument();
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
            new File("C:\\xsd\\main.xsd"));
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(is);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(source); // This is where error occurs
    jaxbMarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

Main.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns="head.003.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ah="urn:random:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:doc1="urn:random:xsd:doc1.1.1" xmlns:doc2="urn:random:xsd:doc2.2.2" xmlns:doc3="urn:random:xsd:doc3.3.3" xmlns:doc4="urn:random:xsd:doc4.4.4" targetNamespace="head.003.001.01" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="urn:random:xsd:head.001.001.01" schemaLocation="appHdr.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="urn:random:xsd:doc1.1.1" schemaLocation="doc1.1.1.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="urn:random:xsd:doc2.2.2" schemaLocation="doc2.2.2.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="urn:random:xsd:doc3.3.3" schemaLocation="doc3.3.3.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="urn:random:xsd:doc4.4.4" schemaLocation="doc4.4.4.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="MainMsg" type="MainMsg1"/>
<xs:complexType name="MainMsg1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ah:AppHdr"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="doc1:Document"/>
            <xs:element ref="doc2:Document"/>
            <xs:element ref="doc3:Document"/>
            <xs:element ref="doc4:Document"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Error retrieved :

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ah:AppHdr' to a(n) 'element declaration' component
```

Comment: You should post your complete schemas. There may be a mistake in one of the imported schemas. Create a share a GitHub project, for instance.

Comment: never tried this before - let me try this and buzz you back